# jquery: find() in the response

Tags: jquery

I have a ajax call

```
success: function (msg) {
    if ($(msg).find('.albumGridViewItem').length) {
        $('#MyAlbums').append(msg).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

This is what i have done.

What I want to do is, if there is a element with .albumGridViewItem in the response(msg), then append+fadein, else it should give alert (theres an error)..

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: how can i do so if there is a element with .albumGridViewItem in the response(msg), then append+fadein, else it should give alert (theres an error)..

Comment: your code already does that and looks correct. If it's not working then tell us what errors you're getting or what is happening instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close at getting it right. What's missing is you need to hide the element before appending it, otherwise it will be visible on append and the `fadeIn` won't do anything.

Like this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    var $msg = $(msg);
    if ($msg.find('.albumGridViewItem').length) {
        $msg.hide().appendTo('#MyAlbums').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/zLYhR/) to se it in action.

Edit: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/zLYhR/1/) will show the alert.

Comment: The append and fadein already works though..? My question was on how to check whether msg contains element with class .albumGridViewItem? If it do then append and fadein, else alert the (msg).. I already tried as you can see on my code, but it doesnt work no alert

Comment: @Karem, It does work. Check the second fiddle and you'll get the alert.